# Rails: Unable to use new `config/secrets.yml`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, secret-key

Anybody know how to set ENV variables in `production.rb` using the new `secrets.yml`?

I'm getting `key: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` for the below:

production.rb:

```
# DOES NOT WORK

ENV["SOME_STUFF_KEY"] = Rails.application.secrets.some_stuff.key
ENV["SOME_STUFF_SECRET_KEY"] = Rails.application.secrets.some_stuff.secret_key

# NOTE THAT THIS WORKS:

# ENV["SOME_STUFF_KEY"] = "abcdefg";
# ENV["SOME_STUFF_SECRET_KEY"] = "123456789123456789";
```

secrets.yml:

```
production:
  some_stuff:
    key: abcdefg
    secret_key: 123456789123456789
```

Comment: Have you tried without nested values? Try key and secret_key immediately after production and see what happens.

Comment: Also, I think your setup defeats the purpose of the new secrets file. In production you should read the values from ENV variables which are set outside of indexed files (such as production.rb you use to export these vars).

Comment: rkon: Without nested values: `production.rb:in `[]=': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)`

Comment: rkon: As for your second comment, I'm not sure I understand. These values are my Facebook app ID and secret key, all sensitive info, so wouldn't secrets.yml be the best place? I like the idea of having all sensitive info gathered at one place.

Comment: For the error just try calling **to_s** on the keys.

Comment: Yes keep the all together as long as you don't commit secrets.yml in your code repository. Or commit it as long as you read from ENV vars which were exported otherwise (not from a committed file). But why would you try to export environment variables with values from a YML file? What uses these ENV vars?

Comment: Thanks! `to_s` did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found any information about nesting like you did with `some_stuff`. The [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml) and all other blog posts just use flat keys as an example:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 3b7cd727ee24e8444053437c36cc66c3
  some_api_key: SOMEKEY
```

> `Rails.application.secrets.some_api_key` returns SOMEKEY in the development environment.

That's why someone created the [dot_secrets gem](https://github.com/rono23/dot_secrets) ("Enable dot syntax on nested Rails.application.secrets")

Comment: Cool thanks! But seems kind of silly having to rely on a gem just to be able to use normal YML?

Comment: Keep in mind: Plain YAML gives you a hash and not an object you can call methods on, like `Rails.application.secrets` does. This is anything but "normal YAML."

Comment: FWIW, my new secrets weren't being reloaded until I issued `spring stop`.

Answer (score 2):

To get nested values like yours you need to use this syntax.

```
Rails.application.secrets.some_stuff[:secret_key]
```

Comment: or...Rails.application.secrets[:some_stuff][:secret_key]